# Share Canvas Images to Facebook

Tags: facebook, canvas, share

Hi Guys i'm at the last step of this project, i've saved my Canvas image on server side and was hoping to now be able to change the share thumbnail for Facebook. Below is the code up to the sharing part.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//Share the current Canvas Image to Facebook
jQuery(document).on('click','#poster',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  /*Save to server*/
  var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: rkax.ajaxurl,
  data: { 
         action: 'raketrad_save_to_server',
         imgBase64: imageData
  }
}).done(function(img_url) {
  console.log(img_url);
 $('body').append('<meta property="og:image" content="'+img_url+'" />');
 FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: window.location.href,
      }, function(response){});

});
```

I am finding that even when the meta property has been appended to the page. Facebook still takes the default URL. How do i go about chaning this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get the share feature going but the feed worked for me

```
 FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: window.location.href,
  picture: img_url,
 }, function(response){});
```

hope this helps anyone else looking for something like this

Comment: I need to put href link facebook in the head? I appreciate if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Adding the opengraph metatags on the local browser version does not work, because the facebook crawler will scrape the "server version" of the page. What you should do, as part of the `'raketrad_save_to_server'` action, is to store the appropriate information on your server, so that the page served at the url you pass to the `FB.ui/share` method will contain the correct meta properties.

Comment: Thanks but it's for a product customization image share so your solution isn't feasible for me.